# How can I get ftp:// links in Chrome (Mac) to open the connection in Transmit?

Tags: mac, google-chrome, ftp

I'm trying to get a link like this to open the Transmit FTP app when clicked from Chrome (I'm on version 16, using OS X 10.7):

`ftp://username:password@example.org`

Clicking a link like that that will simply open up a file-browser-like view in Chrome. *SFTP* links work great. They open right up in Transmit.

(FTP links work fine in Firefox (it'll ask you once which app you want to open). Safari thinks for a bit and then opens Transmit, which throws an error. But my main browser is Chrome.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in Chromium, so it can't be achieved without a plugin.

Here is a link to the issue: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30892